# How do I merge records using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to merge two records using a condition for each column in the row. I'd give you a code sample but I don't know where to start.

```
class Foo
{
    public int i {get;set;}
    public int b{get;set;}

    public string first{get;set;}
    public string last{get;set;}
    }

//...
    var list = new List<Foo>() { 
    new Foo () { i=1, b=0, first="Vince", last="P"},
    new Foo () { i=1, b=1, first="Vince", last="P"},
    new Foo () { i=1, b=0, first="Bob", last="Z"},
    new Foo () { i=0, b=1, first="Bob", last="Z"},
    } ;

// This is how I'd like my result to look like
// Record 1 - i = 1, b = 1, first="Vince", last = "P"
// Record 2 - i = 1, b = 1, first="Bob", last = "Z"
```

Comment: So, to clarify, the last of each group of Foo ordered by b that match on fields i, first & last?

Comment: In what way do you want to merge records? The result looks like the second record, but just selecting one of the records doesn't involve any merging, so how should the result be determined?

Comment: If you notice, b has been merged to equal 1. So I want to perform an AND operation on the b property

Comment: In most languages that allow ints to act as bools 0 AND 1 would be 0.  Do you mean 'OR'?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean OR :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the result, then aggregate the fields from the items in the group:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(f => f.first).Select(
  g => new Foo() {
    b = g.Aggregate(0, (a, f) => a | f.b),
    i = g.Aggregate(0, (a, f) => a | f.i),
    first = g.Key,
    last = g.First().last
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Aggregate` method in LINQ.

First add a method to Foo, say `Merge` that returns a new Foo based on your merging rules.

```
public Foo Merge (Foo other)
{
   // Implement merge rules here ...
   return new Foo {..., b=Math.Max(this.b, other,b), ...};

}
```

You could also, instead, create a helper method outside the Foo class that does the merging.

Now use `Aggregate` over your list, using the first element as the seed, merging each record with the current aggregate value as you go.  Or, instead of using `Aggregate` (since it's a somewhat contrived use of LINQ in this case), just do:

```
Foo result = list.First();
foreach (var item in list.Skip(1)) result = result.Merge(item);
```

How are your merge rules specified?

Comment: I want to perform an OR operation on the b property

Comment: Updated answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I found a non-elegant solution that works

```
var result = list.GroupBy(i=>i.first);
    foreach (IGrouping<string, Foo> grp in result)
    {
        grp.Aggregate ((f1, f2) => {

            return new Foo() {
                b = f1.b | f2.b,
                i = f1.i | f2.i,
                first = f1.first,
                last = f1.last
            };
        });
    }
```